# cross-env not updating meta.env variables with vite + vue3

Tags: vue.js, vite, cross-env

I'm trying to specify env during start command like :

```
"dev": "cross-env VITE_NODE_ENV=development && vite --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080",
```

But when console.log(import.meta.env) there is no VITE_NODE_ENV available. How to deal with this ?

Comment: docs say we should use .env.production, .env.development files, but they are not work for me too

Comment: https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#modes